# How to workout what elements of a quotient ring look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to understand quotient rings. Firstly:

$$\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle x-1\rangle}$$
The above I can understand in a fairly naive way. Since the ideal is generated by a degree one polynomial, 1) we know by the division algorithm that we obtain a $0$-degree polynomial, and hence the above is isomorphic to the integers. Or 2) since $(x-1)\equiv 0$, $x\equiv 1$ and hence it is isomorphic to the integers. I am a little worried about the logic above, but I am fairly sure the result is correct.

> Above is context, now for the question. I.e. TL:DR if you wish for context above.

$$\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle}$$
The ideal above is generated by a degree two polynomial, so by the division algorithm, we obtain all polynomials of the form: $a+bx|a,b\in\Bbb Z$.

Now I don't know what information we have left to ponder over, something like the following? $x\equiv 1\pmod {x^2-3x+2}$ and $x\equiv 2 \pmod {x^2-3x+2}$

What more can we deduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the elements of $$R := \Bbb Z [x] / \langle (x - 1) (x - 2) \rangle$$ "look like" $a + bx$, $a, b \in \Bbb Z$. Put more precisely, each element of $R$ has a unique representative in $\Bbb Z$ of degree $\leq 1$, like you say exactly because of the division algorithm.

This identification alone, however, does not determine the ring structure. The additive group underlying $R$ is isomorphic in the obvious way to the group $$\{a + bx : a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$$ under polynomial addition, which in turn is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$. The multiplicative structure is more complicated: If we denote the equivalence class in $R$ containing an element $p \in \Bbb Z[x]$ by $[p]$, we have
$$[a + bx] [c + dx] = [ac + (ad + bc) x + bd x^2],$$ and we can identify the linear representative of the latter class:
\begin{align}
[ac + (ad + bc) x + bd x^2]
&= [ac + (ad + bc) x + bd x^2 - bd(x - 1)(x - 2)]\\
&= [(ad + bc + 3bd) x + (ac - 2bd)].
\end{align}

Comment: Can you possibly clarify where the $-bd(x-1)(x-2)$ comes from? I can't work it out for sure sorry. I imagine it is something to do with the fact that we are taking modulo $(x-1)(x-2)$ so any multiple of $(x-1)(x-2)$ can be removed without leaving the coset, but why the choice of $-bd$ if my (possibly questionable) logic is correct

Comment: Sure: In order to produce the linear representative, we must subtract off from the given representative $ac + (ad + bc) x + bd x^2$ $(\ast)$ an appropriate multiple of the generator $(x - 1)(x - 2) = x^2 - 3x + 2$ of the ideal (being in the ideal, subtracting by a polynomial multiple of this generator does not change the equivalence class an element represents). Simply by comparing the coefficients of the generator and of $(\ast)$ and the generator, we can see that we must subtract exactly $bd$ times the generator to cancel the quadratic term and hence produce a linear representative.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, that is so clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

From a computational point of view it amounts to saying that, each time you meet $x^2$, you can replace it with $3x-2$, $x^3$ will be replaced with $\,3x^2-2x=7x-6$, &c.